# Android. decrypt data very long time

Tags: android, encryption

I am writing code to encrypt and decrypt data, I used the code below but I have a problem - data decryption takes a very long time (for example for 20 rows it is 6 seconds). Tell me, what am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
public class CryptHelper {

public static KeyStore.Entry createKeyStore(Context context) throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);
    boolean containsAlias = keyStore.containsAlias("com.your.package.name");

    if (!containsAlias) {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
        Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                .setAlias("com.your.package.name")
                .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=Sample Name, O=Android Authority"))
                .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                .build();
        kpg.initialize(spec);
        kpg.generateKeyPair();
    }
    return keyStore.getEntry("com.your.package.name", null);
}

private static byte[] decryptUsingKey(PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] bytes) throws Exception{
    Cipher inCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    inCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    return inCipher.doFinal(bytes);
}


public static String decrypt(String cipherText) throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry("com.your.package.name", null);
    if (entry instanceof KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) {
        PrivateKey privateKey = ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) entry).getPrivateKey();
        byte[] bytes = cipherText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] base64encryptedBytes = Base64.decode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = decryptUsingKey(privateKey, base64encryptedBytes);

        return new String(decryptedBytes);
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

usage

```
String encryptStr = CryptHelper.encrypt(this, "Test");
String decryptStr = CryptHelper.decrypt(encryptStr);
```

Comment: Don't use RSA to encrypt bulk data, instead use a hybrid encryption scheme with AES.

Comment: @JamesKPolk for example?

Comment: You can find plenty of examples online and right here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @JamesKPolk How i use AES for 18+ API?